# Onblur работает только при клике

Tags: html, javascript

Вот есть такой код, которрый реагирует на введённую сумму(если сумма больше 500000 открывает поле, если меньше то поле остаётся не видимым), к ней приделан ползунок, ели ввести цифры в поле в ручную, то все работает а если позунком, то код не отрабатывает - как это исправить?

```
Сумма: <input type="text" id="val26" min="10000" max="10000000" step="5000" value="10 000" class="textbox range" onblur="document.getElementById('flash').innerHTML = (this.value > 500000 ? '<ul>Html код ')" />
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать **onChange** вместо **onBlur**

Comment: onChange включает в себя блюр, без блюра оно не сработает, если надо прям после ввода, то keydown например